# Can you use periods in message keys in a JSF application?

Tags: jsf, internationalization

A typical resource message:

```
adminIndex.webAdminCatalogLabel.articleIndex    = Article Catalog
```

JSF throws:

```
Property 'webAdminCatalogLabel' not found on type java.lang.String
```

Now, I didn't come up with this tokenization myself. I've seen it elsewhere on a Struts application and I liked it. I followed in a Spring application and this part was just fine. I can use an underscore, instead. But I just want to know for sure. Is JSF unable to work with such message keys or is there a switch that needs to be turned on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, definitely you can. Just use the brace notation `#{map['key']}` so that you can put the key in quotes. Given a bundle name of `text`, here's an example:

```
#{text['adminIndex.webAdminCatalogLabel.articleIndex']}
```

Note that this is not specific to JSF, but to EL. Those `#{}` things are not part of JSF, they are part of EL (Expression Language). JSF just happens to make use of it. See also [our EL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info).